# multi-dimensional group by and array aggregation in postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, group-by

I have a table of things

```
id  | registeredAt | organisationId |
=====================================
int | timestamptz  | int            |
-------------------------------------
```

and I want to get out of it a bucketed count of registrations by day, for each organisation.

E.g.

```
organisationId | registrations
=================================================================
 1             | [ {"date": "...", "registrations": 10}, {... ] |
------------------------------------------------------------------
 2             | [ {"date": "...", "registrations": 12}, {... ] |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I *could* do this in several separate queries (one for each organisation) using:

```
select count(*) as "registrations", date_trunc('day', "registeredAt") as date
from my_table
where "organisationId" = 1
group by date;
```

and just map this to each `organisationId` but I was wondering if running this all in postgresql wouldn't be a bit more efficient. The problem is I can't work out how to properly aggregate the data in order to get what I want (which is basically a histogram of registrations for each organisation).

PS.
As a follow on to that, I'm not sure how to structure a query that will give me zeros for days that have no registrations, but this is a minor side-issue.

Comment: Please define: Postgres version, table definition (showing NOT NULL constraints), the time zone defining your days, "days that have no registrations" (where to start and end exactly?). and do you have a separate table listing all organisations of interest, or just what we derive from your `things` table? Your example query provides an `"organisationId"`, which leads to subtly different results than just requesting any organisation in the things table, i.e. NULL for organisations that can't be found in *`things`*.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CREATE TYPE myrowtype AS ("date" date, registrations int);

SELECT organizationId, array_agg( row( registeredAt, cnt )::myrowtype ) as Registrations
FROM (
    select organizationId, date_trunc('day', registeredAt) as registeredAt, count(*) As cnt
    from my_table
    group by organizationId, date_trunc('day', registeredAt)
) x
GROUP BY organizationId
ORDER BY 1
```

If you want to get a result in JSON format (as shown in the question) use this:

```
SELECT organizationId, json_agg(  row( registeredAt, cnt )::myrowtype ) as Registrations
FROM (
    select organizationId, date_trunc('day', registeredAt) as registeredAt, count(*) As cnt
    from my_table
    group by organizationId, date_trunc('day', registeredAt)
) x
GROUP BY organizationId
ORDER BY 1
```